# ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT error upon attempting Postgres data update in Node

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am attempting to update a row of existing data in a Postgres database using Node.js. The code is as follows:

```
var mods = "UPDATE users SET login = '" + now + "' WHERE  name = " + String(req.body.usr) + ";";

client.query(mods, function(err, result) {   
  //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
  done(); 

  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});
```

However I am receiving the following error:

> "throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');" "Error
>   [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the
>   client"

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Working with Postgres and Node.js I am finding to be extremely frustrating.

Comment: The error says that you are calling `res.send()` (or other request end method like `res.json()`) more than once so the second time it tries to set the response headers, the response had finished yet

Comment: VirgilioGM is right, there has to be another call that starts a response.  

Pretty tough to diagnose with the limited code sample.  If there is no other error handling or possible path for a response, then I would check if maybe the done call is actually responding.  But maybe providing more detail will help.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I think I have it simply commenting out the 'res.status(400).send(err);' line.  Does anybody know how I can modify to accept multiple 'WHERE' conditions...?  For example 'WHERE  name = " + String(req.body.usr)' AND 'WHERE cred = " + String(req.body.pass)  ...I am having syntax issues with setting that up.  Any guidance much appreciated.